# Which of the following cases warrant a virtual destructor?

Tags: c++

Case-1:

Base class has a dynamically allocated variable but the derived class doesn't and then I do:

```
Base* p = new Derived;
delete p;
```

Case-2:

Both base and derived class have dynamically allocated variables (derived has additional dynamically allocated variables besides those inherited).
Again, I do:

```
Base* p = new Derived;
delete p;
```

Case-3: 
Base class has no dynamically allocated variables but the derived one does. I do this again:

```
Base* p = new Derived;
delete p;
```

Case-4: Neither base nor derived class has any dynamically allocated variable. Again I do:

```
Base* p = new Derived;
delete p;
```

Or does it cause undefined behaviour in all cases if the virtual keyword is ignored?

Comment: How about doing your homework yourself and learning something? :-)

Answer (score 4):

All of them.

If you `delete` using a pointer that is not the same type as the actual object, the compiler doesn't know how to do it properly unless the destructor is virtual. At that point you get undefined behavior, even if it appears to work properly.

Comment: In the general case all four cases are problematic, but iff the dynamic allocation is the only concern, only case 2 and 3 are problematic, right?

Comment: @Waldheinz: Undefined behaviour is always a concern, so dynamic allocation can't be the only concern.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I'm not that deep into C++ to know if that behaviour is undefined because C++ says so or if there can be cases where it's actually safe to do. But it is always undefined, here's some detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171814/why-is-it-undefined-behavior-to-delete-an-array-of-derived-objects-via-a-base

Comment: @Waldheinz it's always dangerous to rely on the internal workings of the compiler, because those are subject to change. Even though it appears the dynamic allocation should be the only difference, you can't guarantee it.